# error on postback after creating 111 rows or more

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, row, creation

I am dynamically adding rows to a table, everything works fine when the total no. of rows is 110, but it throws an error (after creating on postback) when I increase the rows to 111 or more. I am using .net4, vs2010 premium.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Answer (score 0):

I used to get that kind of an error when I had a WCF service that was sending so much data that it would crash. The consuming web page would get a similar 500 error. In my situation we traced the service and found out the service was only sending most of the data. We had to increase our "buffer" in order to get all of the data.

I would need more information to be of any help in your situation since I do not know if you are calling a web service, a database, or just dynamically creating data in the codebehind.